# How do i resolve 'Timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

We keep getting this error in our production server.

> The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached

this is how i read from database

```
    objDataEngine.InitiateConnectionAsync();
        SqlParameter[] Parameters = new SqlParameter[3];
        ...
        var execResult = await objDataEngine.ExecuteCommandAsync("WebBrandListSelect", CommandType.StoredProcedure, Parameters);

         while (execResult.Read())
         {
           //read from datareader
         }

         objDataEngine.CloseConnection();
```

code for InitiateConnectionAsync is:

```
       public async Task InitiateConnectionAsync()
            {

                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.DataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[this.database];
                builder.InitialCatalog = this.database;
                builder.UserID = this.username;
                builder.Password = this.password;
                Connection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
                await Connection.OpenAsync();
            }
```

function for `ExecuteCommandAsync`

```
  public async Task<SqlDataReader> ExecuteCommandAsync(string commandText, CommandType type, SqlParameter[] parameters = null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 400;
            cmd.Connection = Connection;
            cmd.CommandType = type;
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            cmd = AssignParameters(cmd, parameters);
            SqlDataReader Reader =await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            this.ObjReader = Reader;
            this.ObjSqlCommand = cmd;
            return Reader;
        }
```

and finally the code for `CloseConnection`

```
public  void CloseConnection()
{
    this.Connection.Close();
    this.Connection.Dispose();
    if (this.ObjReader!=null)
    {
        this.ObjReader.Close();
        this.ObjReader.Dispose();
        this.ObjReader = null;

    }
    if (this.ObjSqlCommand!=null)
    {
        this.ObjSqlCommand.Dispose();
    }

}
```

please help if you find anything wrong in my code. Is there any probability my datareader is not properly disposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a connection timeout property on the connection which has nothing to do with the command timeout, so it may be worth trying setting this. You can set it in code or in the connection string, its called "Connect Timeout=" in the connection string if you are using SQL/Server.

I've had a quick look at your code - I'm uneasy about disposing of the connection and then disposing the reader and the command. I think you should dispose command, reader, connection in that order, although I don't normally use dispose code unless I have a reason to - the garbage collector is usually good enough for many scenarios.

If this doesn't help, I would look at system configuration options such as connection pool sizes etc.

Comment: i already set the Connect Timeout to 120 and MaxPoolSize to 1000, that doesnt seem to be the cause. I didnt use try catch block while reading from database, so if any error happens, CloseConnection() is not executed. So now i need to enclose all my codes with it...thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you do not catch errors, it depends on when your Connection object goes out of scope. On web apps, this might be a long time if you have got it (say as a shared object in a class somewhere). So as well as catching errors, it would be a good idea to check the scope of your Connection object. Remember that if it is shared, then this might be very bad, because its Shared in the context of IIS, not a single web page you are using. The usual pattern is to instantiate data access classes during page execution and have connection objects private to the class that are instantiated in the ctor.